# Unable to run npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I just cloned old portfolio page to update from Github.

When running `npm i` I run into the below error

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
```

These are the dependencies that my package json relies on

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "reset-css": "^5.0.1"
  }
```

I can't pull in dependenies, upgrade or anything. How can I resolve this?

Current node version is `v18.14.0`

Comment: Probably has to do with the caret `^` in front of package versions, it instructs node to not update beyond that particular major version. Try removing and then running `npm update` or `npm update -f` if it still doesn't works.

Comment: I tried as you said and still ran into same error.

Comment: Run `npm update -f --verbose` and share a screenshot of the console. Also the log you've shared with the question has **warnings** but not errors, thus app should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`Node.js v18.14.0` at time of writing is fairly new. `gulp` hasn't had a new release since 2019 so I suspect this package.

If you just want to try this old repository, based on the timeframe I would try `node 12`. It's typically not recommended to downgrade this far but if you just want to try an old repository, you will need to. I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to easily switch between Node versions.

I would find a way to not rely on `gulp` and `gulp-sass` if you want to use `Node v18`. I'm still generally developing on Node 16 and sometimes 17 because a lot of projects aren't ready for Node 18 breaking changes.

Comment: I was previously on 16. But thought upgrading could help. Maybe you're right to not rely on `gulp`/`gulp-sass`. Need to rethink things